# MongoDB Best practice for failing over to delayed secondary

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out the best way to quickly recover from a disastrous query (e.g. `dropDatabase()`) that has corrupted the primary and any secondaries.

My current solution requires recovering from a snapshot on MMS, which means 2 hours of downtime to download and untar the file.

My plan is to add a 30-minute delayed secondary to my replica set so I could quickly failover in this disaster case -- I would lose 30 minutes of writes, but this is better than 2 hours of downtime.  Ideally, I could actually have the delayed database replay the oplog up to the bad query first.

Does this approach make sense?  If so, how do you actually promote a delayed secondary (after removing the corrupted servers), ensuring that it doesn't replicate the bad query that corrupted the primary?

Comment: When would be the cases of a database command that would break your production data? I mean is 30 mins really enough of a window? Are your deployment steps upto speed on how to stop code which would damage your production from going live? etc etc

Comment: Please post this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com. StackOverflow is dedicated to programming questions. *Note: in a production setup, those queries should be made impossible.*